# Return array to view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following controller, passing this array of information to my view

```
public function index ()
{
     public function index ()
     {
        $ information = [
        'nroclients' => '10',
        'nroservices' => '20',
        'nrousuers' => '30',
        'nroordensservices' => '40',
        ];
    
         return view ('dashboard.index', compact ('information'));
     }
}
```

how can I access each element separately?
**index.blade.php**

```
number of clients: {{information-> nroclients}} <br>
number of services: {{information-> nroservices}}
```

Does this run in my view should not work?

The reported error is

> (2/2) ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object (View: C: \
>   wamp64 \ www \ sistemtest \ resources \ views \ panel \
>   index.blade.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its an array not an object or json so you should access keys like this in blade:

```
{{$information['nroclients']}}
```

instead of

```
number of clients: {{information-> nroclients}}
```

Comment: I'm waiting for the time to accept your response, do you know how I use a model without applying the use? for example $ Client = new App \ Models \ Dashboard \ Client;

Comment: errr... I really dont understand what are you saying. Could you please explain more